# Php login code, data does not match

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Here is my code that I made when I tried to make a login page to my site. I get wrong details everytime I try to login, I have checked the details several times so that they match, I do get a clear dbconnection so there is not a problem with that either. I do not have an md5 encryption so that I have thought of too... I use LONGTEXT as datatype in my mysql database for storage of name and password. I got 3 rows of information in the table users of the database. ID, Name, password, named exactly as I have written.

I hope this was enough information to get some help?
Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!=""){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name='$email'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if($row['password']==$upass){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        ?>
        <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
        <?php
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: The problem is that we cannot debug your code for you, you have to do that step-by-step. Start from the parameters received in $_POST, through adding error handling to your query, printing out the query and executing it in yiur favourite mysql management tool to see the results, and so on.

Comment: Oh thank you! :) I'm not a software engineer :p

Comment: Why not send the `password` with the SQL query? You also shouldnt have plain text passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do this because will not pass this to the query anyway.

```
$upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
```

The value of the password is not equal to the value of the escaped password. So this will not be accurate.

```
if($row['password']==$upass){}
```

You could just do something like

```
if($row['password']==$_POST['pass']){}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest following fixes to your script..

1) Make sure that the name should be unique in your db table..
e.g. if some one has already registered with name as "admin" then do not allow any other person use that as username( or name in your case) to use.

2) Check name and password both in the query it self.

See the below modified code..

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    if(isset($_POST['login']))
    {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $upass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Name='$email' AND password = '$upass' ");
        if($res) // check if there is any error in the query
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) // check for the number of Name - password pair
            {
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                $_SESSION['user'] = $row['user_id'];
                header("Location: index.php");
            }
            else 
            {
                ?>
                <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
                <?php
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Error while log in: ".mysql_error();
        }
    }   
?>
```

**Note:**
1) Stop using mysql_*. They are deprecated Use [mysqli_](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)* or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

2) Make sure that you have used proper columns names in PHP code, similar to those in the db table.